# Return true or false if element of one list starts with element of another list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

What I have

```
List <String> ignoreList = Arrays.asList("google.com", "something.com/path")
List <String> ignoreCandidates = Arrays.asList("google.com/anotherPath", "anotheritem.com")
```

If an item in ignoreCandidates starts with an item in ignoreList, then I want to return **false**

In this exmaple, **google.com/anotherPath** starts with **google.com** so when I hit that match I want to return **false**

I've tried something along these lines

```
return ignoreList.stream().noneMatch(e -> ignoreCandidates.stream().forEach(c -> c.startsWith(e));
```

The code above doesn't even work. I've seen examples of this being done, but instead of returning true or false they returned a filtered list which isn't what I want.

Example of that: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-find-list-items

Also, I do know that I could accomplish this by just looping over each list and assigning a boolean based off of the result, but I want to know if this is possible through functional programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. It should be:

```
return ignoreList.stream()
                 .noneMatch(e -> ignoreCandidates.stream()
                                                 .anyMatch(c -> c.startsWith(e)));
```

i.e. you require that **none** of the elements of `ignoreList` matches **any** of the elements of `ignoreCandidates`.

Comment: I don't like the indentation. (-:

Comment: @MCEmperor you'd rather use a single long line?

Comment: @Eran Of course not. I don't dislike newlines, but it is that kind of indentation that I don't like.